Making a function inside an if statement run until you get a false value for the conditional using JS in Cypress
I am writing a test in Cypress where I enter two values into two separate inputs and then compare them by clicking a button.  If the button displays "=", I need to reset and reenter two new values until I get something other than "=".  It could be "+" or "-".
I created a function called checkResult() that uses an if statement to check if the conditional is true (text === "="). If it is true, it then calls another function called reEnterInputs(), which resets the value of the inputs and enters two new values.
The issue I am having is that I thought that by using this.reEnterInputs() in the if statement, it would rerun itself until I got a value other than "=". It runs once and it stops. Can someone help?
 describe('template spec', () => {        
          const numberArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
          const  topInput = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberArray.length).toString();
          const  bottomInput = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberArray.length).toString();
           it('Check values inside html element', () => {
            cy.visit('/');
            //Fills out one input
            cy.get('#top').type(topInput);
            //Fills out another input
            cy.get('#bottom').type(bottomInput);
            //clicks button to compare
            cy.get('#compare').click();
            //Runs this function
            checkResult();
          });
        });
        
        **Functions***
    //This function checks the result of the values in the top and bottom inputs
      public checkResult() {
        cy.get('#value')
          .invoke('text')
          .then((text) => {
            if (text === '=') {
              this.reEnterInputs();
              //if the "=" appears again after running reEnterInputs(), I need reEnterInputs() to run again until a value different than "=" is given
            } else {
              cy.log('B');
            }
          });
      }
    
    //This function runs in the if statment
      public reEnterInputs() {
        let numArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
        let topNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numArr.length).toString();
        let bottomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numArr.length).toString();
    
        //Clicks the reset button
        cy.get('#resetValues').click();
        //reenters the number in the inputs
        cy.get('#top').type(topNumber);
        cy.get('#bottom').type(bottomNumber);
        //checks value of inputs
        cy.get('#compare').click();
      }


It runs once and it stops because it's not called anywhere to run again

Ideally I'd like to know more about how the app works (and what it is you expect to test - random inputs don't really test very efficiently).
But technically, to repeat things, put the check in a recursive function.
The input commands can go into the function enterInputs().
function enterInputs() {
  let numArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  let topNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numArr.length).toString();
  let bottomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numArr.length).toString();
  cy.get('#top').type(topNumber);
  cy.get('#bottom').type(bottomNumber);
  cy.get('#compare').click();
}

This is the recursive function. Best practice sets a limit to the number of attempts.
function untilCorrectValueText(attempt = 0) {
  if (attempt > 200) throw new Error('too many attempts');

  enterInputs()
  cy.get('#value').invoke('text').then(text => {
    if (text === '=') {
      cy.get('#resetValues').click();
      untilCorrectValueText(++attempt)
    } else {
      // ...whatever
    }
  })
}

This is the test.
it('my randomized test', () => {
  cy.visit('/');
  untilCorrectValueText()
})

